# Pencil icon next to title doesn't appear in Joomla site

Tags: joomla

Hi i have a problem in a Joomla site that i am editor.

I cannot see the little pencil that allows me to change a Joomla site content when i log in.
I have the rights to change the content but it seems i cannot.

And another question....

How can i see my account settings on that site so i can change the editor? It did showed me the account settings but i cannot seem to see then anymore.

Ps. I do not have access to the administrator page of joomla they just made me editor on the site.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

They'll have to give you access to the front end editor - ask your administrator.  They may have it turned off.

If they gave you permission to see your profile page you may be able to set the editor...again that's an administrator question.